# Запись значения каждого текстбокса в XML тег

Tags: c#, xml, .net

Вот создаю программу, где по нажатию на кнопку, создаются текстбоксы. Как сделать чтобы при создании текстбокса, создавался новый xml тэг и внутрь него записывались данные текстбокса. Когда один текстбокс, я могу записать. Проблемы:
 **как не потерять связку между текстбоксом и тэгом?** Т.к после удаления и вновь создания, они запутаться могут
 **как написать код, для того, чтобы при создании текстбокса, создавался и новый тэг?**
 Можно как в CSS задать им id или как то такое сделать, чтобы по этим связкам работать?

Очень извиняюсь за путаницу, надеюсь смог донести что хотел. Если не поняли, то спросите, отвечу. Заранее спасибо

**UPDATE**

Как правильно написать, чтобы в тэг записались данные, последнего созданного текстбокса?

```
writer.WriteString = this.textbox //(не сработало)
```

Comment: Кхм.. У вас проблемы на уровне понимания синтаксиса языка. Может сначала букварь, а потом программировать?

Comment: Приведите пример XML.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Очень сумбурное описание, попробуем разобраться.

Я понял вопрос так: есть кнопка, на нее нажимаем -> генерируются X текстбоксов, информацию о которых надо сохранить в xml-файл. Правильно понял?

Тогда, первый вопрос, как создаются текстбоксы? Об этом ничего не написано. Предположу, что существует какая-нибудь коллекция, исходя из данных которой генерируются элементы.

Тогда они будут генерироваться через цикл:

```
foreach (_type t in _collection)
{
TextBox tb = new TextBox();
...
}
```

Теперь

> как не потерять связку между
> текстбоксом и тэгом?

Вероятно, что у каждого текстбокса есть какое-то уникальное поле. Где его можно хранить? Вероятно в поле .Tag.

Теперь при создании xml-элемента надо добавить ему атрибут с этим тэгом. Дальше по этому тэгу элемент можно будет легко найти. Не знаю, как вы предпочитаете работать с XML - в C# способов много.

Пока так, будут вопросы - спрашивайте.

---

> А как для общего случая написать?

Ну, если вы нажимаете на кнопку "+" и создаете текстбокс, то определенно можете выбрать нужное вам поле. Его и запишете в тег.

```
TextBox t = new TextBox();
t.Text = "someText"; // берем откуда-то

// Далее тут же добавляем новый XML-элемент, добавляем в него тег со значением t.Text
```

Это элементарно.

Если же надо найти TextBox, стоящий на конкретной месте (например последнем), то придется создать коллекцию из элементов типа TextBox.

Будет что-то вроде:

```
List<object> textBoxes = new List<object>();
textBoxes.AddRange(this.SomePanel.Items.Where(o => o.GetType() == typeof(TextBox)).ToList()); /* создаем коллекцию из элементов нужного типа, расположенных на странице. */
```

И работать с n-ым элементом коллекции. Это немного сложнее.

Comment: @Olter давайте постараюсь изложиться более подробнее и внятнее: Нажимаю на кнопку "+" и при каждом нажатии на кнопку + создаются друг под другом текстбоксы. Есть еще и кнопка "-" при нажатии на которую последне созданный текстбокс удаляется, т.е снизу вверх.
1) как мне сделать, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку + создавался тэг(эту часть знаю), а внутрь тэга записывался стринг находящийся в этом именно последнем текстбоксе. Проблема в том, что я не могу его для общего случая написать. Т.е могу конкретно 

      write.WriteString(textBox1.Text);


А как для общего случая написать?

Comment: Чтобы write.WriteString( текст находящийся в n-ном текстбоксе)?

Answer (score 0):

не сработало потому что доступ к значению текстбокса осуществляется через его свойство Text, то есть писать надо примерно так:

```
// присваиваем переменной firstName значение введенное в текстбокс txtFirstName
string firstName = this.txtFirstName.Text;
```

Comment: Это конечно правильное замечание, но автору вопроса надо пересматривать логику решения. Простым добавлением поля .text там проблему определенно не решить.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы не потерять связку между контролом и тэгом - надо держать их вместе. Проще всего, если у вас будет отдельный класс, который будет содержать в себе контрол - и связанный тэг.

Также имеет смысл, чтобы события контрола прослушивались именно этим самым классом, а не формой напрямую.

Теперь остается одна проблема - форма "из коробки" хранит только список дочерних контролов, а список объектов-связок вам тоже придется где-то хранить. Проще всего, если класс-связка будет контролом - тогда его можно будет напрямую положить на форму.

Таким образом, вам для решения вашей задачи хорошо подойдет UserControl, содержащий в себе текстбокс - и логику для связи с тэгом.

Answer (score 0):

Чего вашему коду не хватает — это отделения контента от представления.

Мне кажется, должна подойти следующая архитектура:

1. (Модель) У вас внутри программы есть список однотипных объектов, представляющих нужные вам данные. Например, в объектах может содержаться строка.
2. (Представление) Ваш UI строит текстбокс как представление объекта из модели. Если добавляется новый объект в модельный список, UI должен автоматически добавить и представление для нового объекта. (Если вы пользуетесь WPF, это легко сделать при помощи `DataTemplate` и `ObservableCollection`.)
3. (Спуск от представления к модели)

   - При изменении данных в текстбоксе, эти изменения должны отразиться в модели. (Если вы пользуетесь WPF, вы можете использовать `Binding`. Для WinForms, вероятно, вам нужен контроллер.)
   - При нажатии на кнопку происходит не прямое создание `TextBox`'а, а отправляется команда на уровень модели. В результате выполнения команды создастся новый модельный объект, который автоматически отобразится, согласно пункту 2.
4. Модель занимается также *сериализацией* в XML. При сериализации для каждого из объектов добавляется соответствующий XML-тег в общий список. Соответствие объектов текстбоксам на этом уровне не играет роли.